# How to draw a mass-spring system with Python?

Tags: python, drawing, figure

I have to draw a mass spring system in python, but I don't know how.
My system needs to be something like
|----M1----M2----| (where M1,M2 are masses, | are walls and - are springs), but then as a nice figure instead of this.

Comment: It will be great if you are using modeling language like modelica, mathematica, and simscape instead of programming language like Python to represent physics based models. Anyways I appreciate your thoughts!

Comment: It is for a school assignment so I have no choice but to do it in Python. Do you maybe know any libraries suited for this?